# Link of React-Router-Dom not working when Link is inside three divs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Am trying to create a dropdown nav but when I put the Link tag from react-router-dom v5 in the div with className="dropdown-links", the URL is not changing and nothing changes it just remains there. But i put the Link above div with className="dropdown__menu information__grid, it works well.

```
 import React from 'react'
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

     const nav = () => {
       return (
         <div className="dropdown">
                    <button className="btn-nav">Bags</button>
                    <div className="dropdown__menu information__grid">
                    <div>
                      <div className="dropdown-heading">Ladies Bags</div>
                      <div className="dropdown-links">
                          <Link to="/all" class="link">All</Link>
                          <Link to="/lastest" class="link">Latest</Link>
                          <Link to="/popular" class="link">Popular</Link>
                      </div>
                  </div>
             </div>
         </div>
           )
        }
```

Comment: Copied your code into a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/link-of-react-router-dom-not-working-when-link-is-inside-three-divs-w3y3q) and other than missing a closing `div` tag it runs without issue. Is there more to your code? Can you create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue we could inspect and debug live?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, i had pointer-events set to none and that was hindering the routing.